# Replicating tables and columns from a mysql database to another

Tags: mysql

My objective is to duplicate the tables and columns with constraints included from one database to another within a mysql server.

Is there any query possible for this purpose ?

This has to be done without copying the table data from one database to another.

Comment: You can [`SHOW CREATE TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html) and see the create statement for a table. Most clients also let you download a dump of the db with or without the data, and you can use that to rebuild the same db

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same by using the two methods mentioned below:

1. Use `CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE other_db_name.other_table;`
2. You can check the create statement by **SHOW CREATE TABLE** and copy that statement to create a new table without copying the data.

I hope it helps!